# Store settings into database row

Tags: java, database

I saw into old system optimized way to store into database row application settings. Something like this

```
10 - enabled option 1;
12 - enabled option 2;
13 - enabled option 3;
```

And the entire number is stored into database as 101213. Do you know what is the name of this pattern and is there a tutorial in Java?

Comment: Maybe it's custom pattern. I saw this before using any sequence of characters or numbers with separator like $ and each sequence indicating special configuration mapped on the code. You might want to check your java code and see if there is kind of mapping when retrieving data from that row

Comment: I don't think there is a pattern for this. It looks like a simple data compression (or encoding/decoding).

Comment: Probably something that the programmer at the time just came up with. If it were me, I'd use bits rather than base 10 numbers.

Comment: Do you know some Java tutorial with this implementation?

Comment: I imagine RealSkeptic means that you could treat each option enabled/disabled as its own column. So you could have a Boolean value mapped to a column for option 1 and another for option 2 and so on. But if they are application-wide settings it would be more usual to store in a properties file rather than the database (unless the database needs them e.g. for certain queries)

Answer (score 2):

Do not save the settings in one value in some clever encoded way, being simply concatenated values or being bit encoding. It's way to complicated to deal with these values.

Instead save the values in a table where each setting has its own row, which might look like this:

```
+----+---------------+-------+
| id | setting       | value |
+----+---------------+-------+
| 1  | SomeSetting   | 42    |
| 2  | AnotherOne    | true  |
| 3  | SomethingElse | 4.56  |
| .. | ...           | ...   |
+--------------------+-------+
```

This way you can simply run a `SELECT` statement to get all/one setting(s) and use an `UPDATE` statement to change the values. You might even consider saving the values in different column types so you get the value you want in the correct type you need instead of parsing/converting them to your desired type.

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of simple compression of data so that you can simply test if your option is enable with `yourline.indexOf("your_option")>-1`

I would recommend to use a table with 1 line per options, but if you really want to have 1 item containing all the options, a better approach is to use a bit per options - the previous approach can lead to error (what if you have more than 100 option ?    101 means enable 10 and 1 or 101 ?  -

To do bit wise, you can use BigDecimal thing:

```
// Let's say you get a String representing your option from your database
String optionFromDB=...;
// optionFromDB is a number like "132456"
// We transform it to bigDecimal:
BigDecimal myOptions=new BigDecimal(optionFromDB);

// Then we can use it.

// enable the option X (X is a number)
myOptions.setBit(x);

// Disable option X
myOptions.clearBit(x);

// Save the options to the db:
String newValToSave=myOptions.toString();

// do something if option x enable:
if (myOptions.testBit(x)){ .... }
```

Here I save the BigDecimal as string, but you can also directly store it as number on the DB.

Comment: Can you extent your code to full working example please?

Comment: I added some code, but as it is simple, hard to have an example without polluting the answer

Comment: Don't worry - add complete answer with minimum working example.

Comment: The code would not be relevant to the question and will be more linked to a use case.  Everything is there : how to get options, how to set / unset them, how to store, how to test for an option.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pattern for that. It looks like somebody was really low on space and was willing to sacrifice readability for space. It's not a particularly good solution IMHO.

Of course, you could do that - you will just need two methods: one would be to convert your options into a string when you want to save options to the database, and other would be to convert string to options when you read it.

However, I would suggest a better way - tore complete pairs such as `"OptionA", "true"` or as single strings (`OptionA=true`). Then you can use `java.util.Properties` with its many benefits, plus you get a code that is reusable in different projects.